# Promoting the site on forums

Tags: discussion, promotion

There are a number of forums that already exist for Raspberry Pi discussion.  RPi.SE has the potential to filter a lot of information from forums, making them more useful for discussion.  However, a lot of forums (especially the one created by the Raspberry Pi Foundation) may see promotion as an attempt to take traffic away from their site.

How can we successfully promote the site on forums, and how can we emphasize the benefit RPi.SE serves to forums?

Answer (score 4):

Few thoughts:

- Don't push for this site to be a "better alternative" to the official forum (or others.) If you sign onto a forum and say words to the effect of "you guys are doing it wrong, check out this place" then you're never going to get anywhere.
- Don't sign up on forums for the sole purpose of promoting this site, or don't promote this site in your first few posts on a forum (because that's what it looks like if you do!) You'll tend to just get treated as a spammer.
- Same goes for pitting this site vs. other sites. I think we should work alongside, not against each other - emphasise the SE model is good for solid Q&A and that discussion type posts may be better elsewhere.
- Respect the decisions others come to, including the foundation. If they decide they don't like it, then don't start shoving it down their throats.

In short, it's probably only worth promoting this site on a forum you're active in, and well respected - otherwise it looks very much like blatant spam. For the most part, it's probably better trying to spread the word via other means - inviting people you think might be interested personally, using social networking sites to promote it and so on.